# Listen to music while watching videos on the browser

Tags: ios, music, mediaplayer

How can I listen to music from the Music app or others (Spotify, etc…) while browsing with Safari? I know that I can put Music in background but it stops whenever I start watching video on Safari. Can I turn off any audio from Safari? Is there any alternative browser that has this feature?

Answer (score 1):

Two apps can't play media at the same time. It's not that Safari is preventing the music from being played but that the media player playing the video from Safari is the front-most media player, overriding any background music. Thus, you can't 'turn off' audio from Safari because it's not from Safari.

Comment: Uhm what about games? Games use audio but I can still listen to music playing them

Comment: @hiru Games which support background music use audio in the game rather than music. Music can be controlled in Control Center and plays when the app is closed, whereas audio does neither.

Comment: Disabling audio from the html5 player in safari can let me play music in background?